# APACHE PIG - error Projected field [Units_Sold] does not exist in schema: group:chararray,D2:bag{:tuple(Item_Type:chararray,Units_Sold:int)}

Tags: apache-pig, vmware, apache-pig-grunt

Good afternoon - I have a Sales Dataset and am trying to see which Item has the most units sold.
Here is my code:

````
        Country:chararray,
        Item_Type:chararray,
        Sales_Channel:chararray,
        Order_Priority_site:chararray,
        Order_Date:chararray,
        Order_ID:chararray,
        Ship_Date:chararray,
        Units_Sold:int,
        Unit_Price: int,
        Unit_Cost: int,
        Total_Revenue: int,
        Total_Cost: int,
        Total_Profit:int);

D2 = FOREACH data GENERATE Item_Type, Units_Sold;

D3 = GROUP D2 BY Item_Type;

D4 = FOREACH D3 GENERATE group, SUM(Units_Sold);

DUMP D4;```

However, I get the error: 

```<file D, line 20, column 36> Invalid field projection. Projected field [Units_Sold] does not exist in schema: group:chararray,D2:bag{:tuple(Item_Type:chararray,Units_Sold:int)}.```

Does anybody know how to fix this? Let me know if you need more info, this is the first qurstion I have posted on here
````

Answer (score 1):

SUM is expecting a bag. The error shows you the schema:

`D2:bag{:tuple(Item_Type:chararray,Units_Sold:int)}`

Therefore change SUM to:

`SUM(D2.Units_Sold)`